# How to send an image and a date in JSON

Tags: php, json

I'm new to JSON and from what I've read it seems pretty difficult to send a date.  I need to send several dates using PHP.

I also need to send an image which I'm thinking would be best done using a base64 encoded string.  Is there a better way?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSON itself does not support sending a `Date` object directly. You can, however, send the timestamp of the date you're working with as a mere number and use

```
var myDate = new Date( jsonObject.timestamp );
```

to recreate a `Date` object. Note here, that PHP uses timestamps based on seconds ( see, e.g., [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.time.php)), whereas JavaScript uses milliseconds as a basis (see, e.g., [here](https://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CE0QFjAA&url=https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date&ei=2iUqUJTGNYy3hAe22ICgCA&usg=AFQjCNG62A29sndTj8GO6o93wmv9lJpSgQ&cad=rja))!

For images I agree, that sending them in a Base64 encoded form is the best way of doing it, if those images are created dynamically or should not be accessible using a URL.

If they are accessible using a URL, sending this URL instead of the image is, of course, preferable.

Comment: timestamp can be in a variety of formats, actually - anything that `Date.parse()` would understand, as Date constructor uses it internally

Comment: @poncha You're right, but PHP uses timestamps in most cases anyway, so this makes it easier (and maybe faster) to parse for JavaScript.

Comment: It may as well be coming from a DB, where an `ISO` date can be stored, so this can be passed as-is, without conversion in php...

Comment: +1 for great explanation.  I'll try it this way. Thanks for the advice @Sirko.

Answer (score 0):

You cant.

> Try to send the Date as miliseconds.
>
> Try to send a url to the Image.

Comment: Inlineimages not supported by all browsers.

Answer (score 0):

JSON is just a string with some formatting rules. You can create date with

```
$arr = array('date' => time());
echo json_encode($arr);
```

You can send image in Base64, but if you can, use URL.